# how to rotate two dimensional array value using numpy in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, rotation

Hi all I need to rotate two dimensional array as shown in the given picture. and if we rotate one set of array it should reflect for all the problems  if you find out please do help me to solve the issue

input:

[image]

output:

[image]

Thankyou

I have tried slicing method to rotate the values but it doesn't give the correct values

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv("/content/pipe2.csv")
df1= df.iloc[6:10]+df.iloc[13:20]
df1
```

Comment: What do you mean by rotate ? please give expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) and the DataFrame constructor:

```
N = -2
out = pd.DataFrame(np.roll(df, N, axis=1),
                   columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```

Example output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0  3  4  5  6  7  1  2
```

Used input:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    import pandas as pd 
    df = pd.read_csv("/content/pipe2.csv")
    df1=pd.DataFrame(data=df)
    df1_transposed = df1.transpose()
    df1_transposed
```